# Superset - How to create a user on superset

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, apache-superset

I have Google OAuth 2 enabled for superset login. I want to use Embed dashboard. I have checked the documentation and it requires one single user with password (with Gamma Role). We can use this user to create access token which can be used to generate guest token and we can give this guest token in the config.
My question is, how can we create the user with gamma role? There is no option to create a user with a password on the UI level. AFAIK, we can't add the user from the config. I am stuck at this point like how to create a user on superset. I was thinking it would be easy but i didn't even able to find any doc related to it. Can someone please help me?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superset-ui/embedded-sdk